# Python function unbearably slow

Tags: python, jupyter

I'm taking a class on numerical methods for computational physics.
I have this function below, which works fine, but becomes slow af after the 12-13th iteration.
I know python is slow, but I never knew it's this slow. Can someone tell me the reason for such a slow down?

```
def fixpt(x0, es, imax):
    g = lambda x: 3 * (x**3) + x - 3 + x
    xr = x0
    x = []
    e = []
    it = []
    for i in range(imax):
        xrold = xr
        xr = g(xrold)
        if xr != 0:
            ea = abs((xr - xrold)/xr)*100
        it.append(i)
        x.append(xr)
        e.append(ea)
        if ea < es:
            break
    return it, x, e
```

Comment: python isnt "slow", its actually "fast enough" for most tasks. The "slow-ness" is only a relative term compared to some other languages. Usually, when you hit a speed bottleneck, You need to ask if there's a better way to do something. Dont blame the language, optimize the code instead.

Comment: python is not slow, your code is, you should write what is your function supposed to do and provide benchmarks as well

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning what it's supposed to do, it's basically a root finding method called 'fixed point iteration'. I'm using it to find the root of 3*x^3 + x - 3.

Comment: @RockyLi isnt it `2x - 3` ?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying a pickard or fixed point iteration in a very bad function, which makes your method diverge, hence your code is slow.

Either try another method or replace the function.

Example: replace f(x) by 1 / (1 + f(x)) - 1 (same roots)

```
def fixpt(x0, es, imax):
    g = lambda x: 1 / (3 * (x**3) + x - 3 + x + 1) - 1

    xr = x0
    x = []
    e = []
    it = []
    for i in range(imax):
        xrold = xr
        xr = g(xrold)
        if xr != 0:
            ea = abs((xr - xrold)/xr)*100
        it.append(i)
        x.append(xr)
        e.append(ea)
        if ea < es:
            break
    return it, x, e
```

Comment: Cool, I feel stupid now. Here's the video btw for people to follow along [Computational Physics Lecture 8, Comparison of Bracketing and Open Methods for Root Finding.](https://youtu.be/OviWvWCkmh0?t=900)